# Ubuntu Theme installer crashes whenever I try to install a new theme?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, themes, personalization

I am very bored of the default themes in Ubuntu, not because they are bad just because I get bored easily!

I decided to visit Gnome's Theme library and found a theme I like. I downloaded the theme and tried to use the install feature in the theme panel. As soon as I click okay after finding the theme package my system freezes.

I decided to try the other way and selected open with (Theme installer) which did exactly the same thing.

Is there a terminal command to install themes or a way to reset the theme manager?
I am using Natty and Gnome 2.32.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install a theme from an archive using the command line by running:

```
tar xavf ARCHIVE -C ~/.themes
```

(replacing `ARCHIVE` with the path to the theme archive)

If it is a zip archive, use:

```
unzip ARCHIVE -d ~/.themes
```

Answer (score 1):

If Your PC freezes by installing the themes through Gnome Appearance you'll have to extract the themes to `/home/username/.themes/` or `/usr/share/themes`.

Inside the theme folder there must be 2 folders, gtk-2.0 and metacity.

Also make sure that the file you downloaded contains those folders and is not in this order:
file>folder>subfolder>theme, it has to be file>theme>gtk & meta.

*Where file is:tar, zip, etc.*