# Installing a new theme on 12.04

Tags: themes

How can the "Clearlooks compact" theme be installed on 12.04 running Unity and MyUnity?  The link says to drag a link from the author's webpage to the `Appearance` window but nothing happens when I do that.

[Link to information on Clearlooks compact](http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/11/04/clearlooks-compact-gnome-theme/)

Comment: There used to be a "Themes" tab in the Appearance windows where tarred themes could have been dragged&dropped. As you can see, the theme is quite old (2007/2008), and I am not quite sure it's been tested on any recent versions of Ubuntu. If you feel adventurous, try the [manual process](http://askubuntu.com/a/56499/20054). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could also install "Advanced Settings" using the software center. With regard to creating a folder in your home directory, I think it should be in lowercase;

instead of creating a folder called ".Themes", try creating a folder called ".themes". You might also consider creating a folder called ".icons" too.

Comment: for my Ubuntu 13.04 **.themes** worked instead of **.Themes**, Thanks @Adeeb

Answer (score 0):

you can install themes manually from Ubuntu tweak .You can select theme from instal theme option .

to install Ubuntu tweak

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa 
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Look at the image for clear idea [image] , there from install theme you can install themes manually .

Answer (score 0):

Before install themes manually from Ubuntu tweak

**Created a new folder ".Themes" in home**

download and extract the theme into this folder.

After that you will be able to see and install it from tweak.
Of course the theme must be for unity.